# Explaining circular dependency in make

Tags: makefile, circular-dependency

Make thinks I have a circular dependency:

```
$ make blah > /dev/null
make[1]: Circular all <- all dependency dropped.
```

Is there a way to get make to print out the path by which it is circular? This is a very big and complicated Makefile that I did not write and I am finding it near futile to figure out by hand.

Any other technologies people have for resolving circular dependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
make[1]: Circular all <- all
```

All right, two things:

1) `all <- all` means that that's the whole path. That's right, `all` is a prerequisite of `all`.

2)`make[1]` means this is recursive Make. Somewhere in your makefile there is a command to `$(MAKE) all` (probably obscured by variable names, functions, arguments, whatever).

Does that help?

Comment: Oh, wow, crazy, Thanks! That makes so much more sense. I fear that the recursive make will be in a generated Makefile which will be impossible to read, but this will make the search a heck of a lot easier. Thanks again.